# Can I do TDD for Android status bar notifications?

Tags: android, tdd

In order to use test-driven development principles for code involving the Android status bar, I would need to write tests that verify an expected state has been achieved. For example, a little unit test like the following would allow me to verify that the notification I intended to put up is actually showing:

```
public class NotificationTest extends AndroidTestCase {

  public void testCanNotify() {
    // setup SUT
    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error, "ticker", 0);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, null, 0);
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "title", "text", intent);
    int id = 123;

    // exercise SUT
    mgr.notify(id, notif);

    // verify result
    // QUESTION: HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SAY:
    // assertTrue(mgr.isShowing(id));

    // teardown
    mgr.cancel(id);
  }
}
```

So as the example shows, the notification manager itself does not seem to have any diagnostic methods such as `isShowing(id)` or `get(id)` which I could use for the "verify" step in the test.

I have looked at the excellent Robotium toolkit, but they are very specific about testing a single application, so they don't cover notifications.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't normally test whether a third party or system api works as expected. I would use a mock `NotificationManager` and verify whether my production code calls `notify` with the correct parameters. Whether the *real* `NotificationManager` behaves properly isn't really something you control.

If `NotificationManager` is resistant to mocking you can try wrapping it in a thin class that's under your control.

The only time I test a third party or system api is when it is poorly documented and I need to confirm a guess about its behavior. These kind of tests are usually thrown away once I have my answer. If this is the case and you are finding it difficult to test using a test framework you can always create a simple application and visually verify the results.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me. In fact, the intention was not to test the notification manager, but rather cross-dependencies between my own various activities. I see your point that this would best be done in a mock context -- I'll look into this.